# Out Of disk, but still boots

Tags: grub2, disk

I have a HP Compaq nx6310 notebook wth 4gb memory & a new 250gb hdd. After installing Ubuntu 12.04, i got an "out of disk" error & was unable to boot. I rebooted in live, instaled & ran Boot Repair then rebooted. Grub menu loaded fine, followed by "out of disk.....press any key to continue". I pressed a key & Ubuntu booted, a bit slow but still booted.
So here are my questions:
1- Since Ubuntu DOES boot, should I just leave it alone?
2- If I need to fix this, HOW do I do it?
3- What causes this error?

```
$wolf@lpc-1:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       230G  9.1G  209G   5% /
udev            1.6G   12K  1.6G   1% /dev
tmpfs           655M  868K  654M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.6G  260K  1.6G   1% /run/shm
wolf@lpc-1:~$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, so it seems to be a problem with GRUB. I found this info in the [official Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingUbuntuOnBigDisk). I know you already know how to get going with [boot repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/), but I will include it in case you forgot, or someone else is having the same issue.

You can either download the [boot repair ISO](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/), burn it to a CD and boot from that, or you can use a regular Ubuntu Live CD. When using a regular Ubuntu Live CD you will need to:

> - boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
> - choose "Try Ubuntu"
> - connect internet
> - open a new Terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), then type:
>
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get
>   update
>   - Press Enter.
>
> - Then type:
>
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
>   - Press Enter

The information on getting boot repair also came from the [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

Now, fire up boot repair, click the `Advanced options` -> `GRUB options` tab, and check the `ATA disk support (solves the [out-of-disk] error)` option, then `Apply`. Reboot, and hopefully that will take care of the issue.

[image: Boot Repair - Advanced Options - Grub Options]

If still not good, create a separate /boot partition at the start of the disk: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

Answer (score 2):

When one gets the `Out of disk` error, there are two solutions to try (in this order):

1. First try the **`ATA disk support`** option of [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) as described by reverendj1, then reboot. This is very easy, but it does not always solve the problem.
2. Then, if still not good, **create a little separate /boot partition** at the start of the disk. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition

For more information, see the tutorial that describes the procedure for installing Ubuntu on a big disk: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingUbuntuOnBigDisk

Comment: I tried both, to no avail. Now instead of some errors but bootable system I get unbootable system with 'bash-like grub', in both cases.

Comment: Please indicate your current [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) URL, so that we know your current situation.

Comment: I was about to do it but **my problem got solved somehow.** What I did was restoring a backup of my disk using CloneZilla. I was getting the error (see the original question) for months now, did the image yesterday and restored the very same image. Maybe it has something to do with the peculiar property of CloneZilla http://askubuntu.com/questions/111399/why-clonezilla-needs-to-reinstall-grub My problem is gone fortunatelly but here's Boot-Info URL I got during my attempt with boot-repair http://paste.ubuntu.com/1197560/