# "hd0 out of disk" / "hd0 write error" (still boots)

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, boot-repair

I was doing a series of upgrades of my desktop which had 10.04, aiming for 12.04. Somewhere in the middle, GRUB began displaying "error: hd0 out of disk / press any key to continue", but the boot continued without problems. I decided a fresh install of 12.04 from a CD would be faster and hopefully eliminate the error, but it persisted.

I then used boot-repair according to this topic 
[Out Of disk, but still boots](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173086/out-of-disk-but-still-boots)
choosing the option of ATA disk support. This led to some scary errors.

So I followed the directions of 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootPartition
creating a 1G partition at the start of the disk and running boot-repair. Now when booting Ubuntu, it says "error: hd0 write error / press any key to continue" and again boots like normal. How do I solve this error?

Here are the current results of running bootinfoscript: http://pastebin.com/xJwbZcKg

Any help is appreciated.

```
grub> ls -l
Device hd0: Not a known filesystem - Total size 312581808 sectors
    Partition hd0,msdos5: Not a known filesystem - Partition start at 300505088 - Total size 12075008 sectors
    Partition hd0,msdos3: Filesystem type ext2 - Last modification time 2012-11-20 20:39:28 Tuesday, UUID 497becdd-c89d-4fcf-8f82-61e37fdc7881 - Partition start at 2048 - Total size 2048000 sectors
    Partition hd0,msdos1: Filesystem type ext2 - Last modification time 2012-11-20 07:43:41 Tuesday, UUID deb68dbd-c809-4b2a-9047-a58349e67375 - Partition start at 2050048 - Total size 298452992 sectors
Device hd1: Not a known filesystem - Total size 976773168 sectors
    Partition hd1,msdos1: Filesystem type ntfs, UUID D6942BD2942BB3C1 - Partition start at 63 - Total size 976751937 sectors
```

Comment: At the grub menu, press `c` to go to the console and type `ls -l` and edit your question to show the output.

Comment: How do I write this output to a file from within the console so I can paste it here?

Comment: You don't; you will have to retype it or take a photo.

Comment: Okay, there's some info.

Comment: Run `Boot-Repair`. When asked if sda is amovible, answer `Yes` (even if it is not in reality), then click the `Recommended Repair` button. This will reinstall GRUB in the MBR of your Ubuntu disk, and a generic bootloader in your Windows disk. Please **indicate the URL** that will appear.

Comment: Now it is back to saying "error: hd0 out of disk".
This time, while repairing, it said "the boot files are far from the start of the disk", even though they should be on the 1G partition at the start.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/1375101/