# Grub error: out of disk on Ubuntu server 12.04 after power interruption

Tags: grub2, raid, data-recovery, grubrescue, crash

I've got an Ubuntu server set up that has been running happily for a year or so with no problems to speak of. It's configured in a RAID-1 to keep everything nice and backed up. Yesterday we had a brief power flicker following some lightning. When I went to power everything back up today, I got `error: out of disk.` Looking around with `ls` shows me eight volumes. I get various errors trying to `ls` them:

- hd0: `unknown filesystem`
- hd1: `unknown filesystem`
- md/0: `unknown filesystem`
- md/1: `unknown filesystem`
- hd0,msdos: `bad filename`
- hd0,msdos1: `unknown filesystem`
- hd1,msdos2: `bad filename`
- hd1, msdos1: `bad filename`

Booting into a GUI with a Live CD shows me two drives that I can't access. The searches I've done so far have suggested that the problem might be a corrupted grub.cfg. 1) How can I fix that, and 2) do I need to take any special steps since I've got a RAID-1 setup?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the raid utility to see if you have any damaged disks?

Comment: I have not, no. Can I get at that from BIOS?

Comment: Have you tried [these suggestions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/173086/out-of-disk-but-still-boots)?

Comment: Usually the raid utility comes up after the BIOS messages... depends from system to system to get into it. Sometimes CTRL+I, CTRL+H ... have a look at your boot messages. It will surely say which keys to press to get in the setup.

Comment: I remember having the same error; was caused by the fact that grub could not read beyond 128GB on my 160GB-sized drive (a BIOS flaw). Problem disappeared after replacing grub.cfg by an exact copy of the file (probably just dumb luck that the replacement file was located in 'lower' disk blocks). Back then, I didn't know you're not supposed to edit grub.cfg yourself; maybe I should have tried `sudo update-grub` instead. If it happened today, I'd try @kraxor's suggestion; good chance this 'ATA disk support' repair option will do the same relocation of grub.cfg, but in a more controlled manner.

Comment: Sweet, boot-disk-repair did the trick! Thanks, kraxor. I'll mark this as a duplicate. Cheers all!